# Motivation of geometric analysis

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

Geometric analysis in some sense tries to make sense of calculus on spaces where we don't require any smoothness (for example metric measure spaces). What are the type of problems that motivate these kind of studies?

Comment: I think, the usual meaning of [Geometric Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_analysis) is different, it primarily includes study of PDEs of geometric origin. I suspect, what you mean geometric measure theory and the theory of metric measure spaces (maybe even more). I suggest, you clarify your question. There are many instances where one is forced to do geometry and analysis in "low regularity setting," even when dealing with Analysis on Manifolds. Maybe include references to papers/books that you have in mind.